# Angular 8 FCM push notification not working

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, push-notification, angular8

I Implemented fcm based on the link

The Token is generated on request. The postman shows 200 ok message send. But I am not sure if the service is listening for new message because the new message is not showing on the console.
version details

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.29
Node: 14.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.29
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.29
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.29
@angular/cli                      8.3.29
@angular/fire                     5.2.3
@angular/http                     7.2.16
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.29
@schematics/angular               8.3.29
@schematics/update                0.803.29
rxjs                              6.6.7
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

packages

```
 {
  "name": "ang7",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --open --port 5004",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "crypto": "ng crypto"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-webpack": "~0.803.29",
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^8.0.1",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "decode-html-entities": "^1.1.10",
    "firebase": "^7.24.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.7",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "ng-marquee": "^9.2.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.2.3",
    "ngx-owl-carousel": "^2.0.7",
    "ngx-pagination": "^4.1.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^7.2.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^9.1.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.29",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.29",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.0/firebase-messaging.js');
firebase.initializeApp({
  config
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

messaging.service.ts

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireMessaging } from '@angular/fire/messaging';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'
@Injectable()
export class MessagingService {
currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null);
constructor(private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging) {
this.angularFireMessaging.messaging.subscribe(
(_messaging) => {
_messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
_messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
}
)
}
requestPermission(userid:any) {
this.angularFireMessaging.requestToken.subscribe(
(token) => {
console.log(token);
console.log(userid);
},
(err) => {
console.error('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
}
);
}
receiveMessage() {
this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe(
(payload:any) => {
console.log("new message received. ", payload);

this.currentMessage.next(payload);

})
}
}
```

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,

  // URL of development API
  apiUrl: 'api',
  firebase: {
    config
  }
};
```

app.module.ts

```
      AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
      AngularFireAuthModule,
      AngularFireMessagingModule,
```

app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit()
{
  this.messageService.requestPermission(this.loggedInUserId);
              this.messageService.receiveMessage()
              this.message = this.messageService.currentMessage;
}
```

Comment: Does it show any error?

Comment: no I have fixed the problem by using yarn however the message is not displayed when it is on the foreground